# Mounting an ISO image with readwrite permission

Tags: iso-image, osx-mountain-lion, hdiutil

I am following [these instructions](http://jordan.broughs.net/archives/2008/03/creating-cross-platform-windows-and-mac-installer-cds) for creating a cross-platform CD. I am coming across a problem in Mountain Lion where I cannot mount the image as read-write.

When I enter the following in Terminal:

```
hdiutil attach -readwrite ~/2013CD.iso
```

I get the following message:

```
hdiutil: attach failed - Function not implemented
```

Is there any way around this? I need to be able to mount the image as readwrite to make changes to it.

Comment: PS: I read your link. I am not sure how step 5 could ever have worked unless hdiutil internally does what I described as step 1.

Comment: Yes, step 5 doesn't work, but I don't need the background image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ISO 9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) (CD images) are **not** designed for writing. The entire filesystem is designed for efficient read only access.

If you want to change part of an .iso you have three options:

1. Copy all data. Change the copy. Generate a new iso file.
2. If the iso is part of a [multi-session CD](http://www.cdrfaq.org/faq02.html#S2-5), you can add new files and change the index. This will not change the old files, nor can you gain space by erasing files.
3. Use an [overlay filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS). All writes go to the non-iso part, but show up as if they were in the iso. This is how many live CDs work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason I need to mount as read-write is to have the folder open on mount using `sudo bless -folder /Volumes/CD -openfolder /Volumes/CD` can I do this without mounting as read-write?

Comment: No idea. I am not an Mac user. However this URL seems to indicate that bless no longer is needed for OS/X. ( https://discussions.apple.com/thread/354645?start=0&tstart=0 ). Are you trying to make a CD image for ancient Mac OS 8?

Comment: That discussion seems to refer to blessing the system folder, rather than a disk image. This is still needed to allow a folder to open when the disk is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The workaround is use a Mac running OS X 10.6.8.

Mountain Lion seems to block it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.afp548.com/index.php/Mount_DMG_Read_Write:

> ...attach the read-only image as with the shadow option:
>
> ```
>     hdiutil attach -owners on your.dmg -shadow
> ```
>
> After typing this command, the image will be attached as a new device
>   to your operating system. Usually this is shown from the command line.

It's the `-shadow` option that enables this.

Comment: has no effect with iso

Comment: With a bit more details to this approach https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94836/how-can-i-modify-a-dvd-image-iso-and-then-burn-a-new-dvd